# How to correctly fetch for retweets with TwitterOAuth php class?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I can't make it work. I have valid credentials, i'm trying to fetch retweets of an specific tweet using this code (i previously authenticated):

```
$retweets= $twitConn->get("/statuses/retweets/".$tweet_id.".json", array('count'=>100));
foreach($retweets as $rt){
    //... some extra stuff
}
```

I've also tried omitting the ".json", but i always get:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  <b>/home/content/70/8339770/html/app/retweets.php</b> on line <b>81</b><br />
```

and i get no output with print_r($retweets). Thanks in advance! I would really appreciate if you could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not getting any data at all, check if all Oauth parameters are set. Also try printing out the tweet ID.

Use this as the api request.

```
$request = "api.twitter.com/1/statuses/{$id}/retweeted_by.xml";
```

Comment: Thanks, i got a hint from your answer. I had to make the request like this:     
    $retweets= $twitConn->get("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweets/".$tweet_id.".json", array('count'=>100));

that is, adding the "http://api.twitter.com/1/" to the request url.